# Checking window width to target smaller browsers doesn't work on page load

Tags: jquery, window

I'm attempting to target smaller browser sizes (i.e. mobile devices) using jQuery. Currently I do this with the following code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){

    function isMobile(){
        if ( $(window).width() <= 600 ) {
            // Do mobile-targeted stuff
        };
    };
    isMobile();
```

... and later on I also bind the `isMobile()` function to a re-size event...

```
    $(window).resize(function(){
        isMobile();
    });

});
```

I'm testing on my Android device, but the function doesn't seem to fire on page load. It *does* fire however when rotating the screen to portrait from landscape. It also works perfectly in chrome on my desktop.

Should I be using a different criteria in my if statement, or could it simply be in the wrong place? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just as an FYI, if you're doing this to amend styling you should use @media CSS queries instead.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - yes, I do - but I also need to monkey around with some javascripts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use ['load' event not ready event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onload?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/window.onload)

```
window.onload = function() {
  doSomethingElse();
};
```

Detect your  device using [**user agent**](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/navigator.shtml) .

> //returns true if user is using one of the following mobile browsers
>   var ismobile=navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPad)|(iPhone)|(iPod)|(android)|(webOS)/i).

Comment: I've often been tempted to use user agent sniffing, but it's had such a bad reputation I'm hesitant to start. Either way, the onload (or rather `$(window).on('load',function(){...})`) technique worked. Thanks.